# Incrementally probing/reading stream with AVIOContext

Tags: ffmpeg, libavformat

Trying to implement stream demuxing/decoding in memory, using producer/consumer idiom.
The producer reads data from network and pushes it into a buffer. The consumer reads data from this buffer and forwards it to avformat.

According to ffmpeg docs, the only way to implement in-memory processing is using `AVIOContext`, providing `read` function for it.

The problem is that if there is too few data in buffer, read function returns 0 and avformat thinks that it's `EOF`, producing an error.
Specifically this happens on `avformat_open_input/avformat_find_stream_info` calls, where avformat tries to probe given data. Sometimes it work, sometimes not, depending on input buffer size.

I've tried to return `EAGAIN` from the `read` function (seemed reasonable), but it doesn't work.

As workaround I've increased input buffer size, accumulating more data before passing it to avformat, but it's waste of memory (there could be hundreds/thousands streams) and can't be a general solution since we don't know exactly how much data will be needed

Is there any way to tell avformat that there will be more data, but later?